# Does the following pseudocode have mutual exclusion, indefinite postponement, neither or both?

Tags: c, process, semaphore, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

For the following, I'd like to know what would happen in the case below:

```
//global declarations
Boolean in1=false, in2=false;
Process P1::
while(1){
  //entry protocol
  while(in2){
    in1=true;
  }
  //--critical section --
  //exit protocol
  in1=false;
}
Process P2::
while(1){
  //entry protocol
  in2=true;
  while(in1){
    in2=true;
  }
  //--critical section --
  //exit protocol
  in1=false;
}
```

Just a bit stumped with this at the moment, because I think it just lacks mutual exclusion - but just wanted to make sure!

Comment: Mutual exclusion is a facility provided by the OS - so no it does not

Comment: It looks to me like it has nothing but data races and undefined behavior.

Comment: To achieve mutual exclusion, use the mutex() facility, using the same mutex name for both critical sections of code. otherwise, as was mentioned by @R, the result will be data races and undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudocode doesn't have proper mutual exclusion. Consider P1 executing first:

- Since initially `in2=false`, P1 gets over its entry protocol and enters the critical section.
- If P2 executes then, since still `in1=false`, P2 gets over its entry protocol and enters the critical section, too, thus no mutual exclusion.

Regarding indefinite postponement:

- After P2 executed `in2=true`, `in2` is never again set to `false`.
- So, P1 cannot get over its entry protocol's `while(in2)` loop and is postponed in(de)finitely.